# How to Update my Entity Object in Database without Setting each property manually?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm updating my database tables using entity Framework but setting each property manually.

```
 using (BmEntities b = new BmEntities())
        {
            var curUser = b.Distributor.Where(k => k.ID == updated.ID).First();

            curUser.UserEmail = updated.UserEmail;
            curUser.UserName = updated.UserName;
            curUser.UserAdres = updated.UserAdres;
            curUser.UserLast = updated.UserLast;
            curUser.Pass = updated.Pass; //these properties goes too much
            b.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Can you show me a simple example instead of the one above?
What should I do if those properties goes to 20-30? My friend told me something about AutoMapper but i could not find a simple example like mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an Extension method from another forum, it solves my problem where AutoMapper not.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static void CopyPropertiesFrom(this object destObject, object sourceObject)
    {
        if (null == destObject)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destObject");
        if (null == sourceObject)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceObject");

        Type destObjectType = destObject.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourcePi in sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            PropertyInfo destPi = destObjectType.GetProperty(sourcePi.Name);
            if (null != destPi && null != destPi.SetMethod)
            {
                object sourcePropertyValue = sourcePi.GetValue(sourceObject);

                destPi.SetValue(destObject, sourcePropertyValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this extension method I am now able to copy all properties at once from the given object.

```
 public static void Update_User(Distributor updated)
 {
    using (BmEntities b = new BmEntities())
    {
        var curUser = b.Distributor.Where(k => k.ID == updated.ID).First();

        curUser.CopyPropertiesFrom(updated); 

        b.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```